# Xpath worked during script creation not working when replaying

Tags: xpath

HTML Tag:

```
<a href="/candidate/updateprofile.html">
    <span class="no-of-jobs">100%</span>
    <span class="grey-text">Profile Strength</span>
    Update your profile </a>
```

Earlier when I created the script, it did work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@href,'updateprofile')]")).click();
```

Now it is not clicking on Update your profile

Comment: Give us a bit more context. It might stop working for hundred different reasons.

Comment: Please edit your question with the error you are receiving.

Comment: Check xpath whether it's same as before

Comment: xpath you have corresponds to your html. So there could could be two kind of reasons. 1 (unlikely) there are some elements which are not links but which have href attribute with 'updateprofile' value. 2 (likely) your link is not interactable due to some reason by the moment you invoke click method.

Comment: Xpaths can be brittle. Minor changes can cause the path to change. If you have an element id to target then I suggest using that.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath can change on reloading page. Also xpath is given the least priority while locating a web element while providing a web application testing services (automation). Priority should be ID,Class > CSS > Linktext > Partial Text > Xpath.

You can try linktext or partial linktext here. It may help. Below is the syntax

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Update your profile")).click();

OR

driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Update")).click();

Hopefully, It will work. If it still fails to click on the element then you need to provide the whole error along with the html page.